# Internet explorer gives total webpage height as "0"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, offsetheight

I am trying to get total height of webpage using javascript as follows

`var pageHeight = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;`

works fine for me in other browsers but Internet explorer returns a value '0' for it. why?

Comment: Which version IE? Their versions are as different as black and white..

Comment: @techfoobar IE 10. the latest one!

Comment: Your code works fine in IE9 and IE10 both, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gpht/1/). I think the reason for your confusion is that all browsers have a different idea of what the `offsetHeight` is - it's not identical to the viewport, and I think you're looking for that.

Comment: if you're in IE10, have you checked that your page is actually in IE10 standards mode, and not compatibility mode or quirks mode. IE10 itself should be fine, but these older modes will definitely have issues like the one described.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in all browsers :

```
var pageHeight = Math.max(document.height, document.body.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight);
```

Don't forget to execute the code after the document is loaded.

EDIT : I let this in hope it works but I have no way to test it in all browsers and I'm not 100% sure. It's adapted from jQuery's source.

Comment: @dystroy Throws NaN on alert :(

Comment: for the executing code after document is loaded, i think its been taken care of since it works in other browsers